# How to use Symbol font in GMT PSTEXT?

Tags: bash, ascii, gis

I am writing a label on a map using Generic Mapping Tools, and I want to use the `\alpha` symbol (α).  This symbol is provided in the Symbols font in GMT, and [corresponds to octal code 141](http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/classes/Intro_GMT/gmt_www/gmt/doc/html/GMT_Docs/node160.html).  I explicitly declare that I want to use the Symbols font in my GMT defaults, as well as in my PSTEXT command:

```
gmtdefaults -D > .gmtdefaults4;
gmtset FONT_LABEL 12 FONT_ANNOT_PRIMARY 12 MAP_LABEL_OFFSET 0.2 PS_PAGE_ORIENTATION portrait MAP_GRID_PEN_PRIMARY 0.5p COLOR_NAN 255 FORMAT_GEO_MAP +ddd:mm:ss MAP_GRID_PEN_PRIMARY 0.25p,gray;

# making the map and other vaguely unrelated stuff, including setting
# variables i and output, which are not related to the behavior here

label="8.9 6 \141 = "$i;
echo $label | pstext -JX3.4c -R0/3.4/0/3.4 -Gwhite -W0.5p -F+f12 -O -N >> $output
```

Nonetheless, my output is the letter `a`, corresponding to `\141` in the standard font.  How can I get GMT to use the Symbols font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Symbols font is not invoked unless the label explicitly requests it using the `@~` code, as explained in the GMT PSTEXT documentation under [Description](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/5.3.2/pstext.html#description).  No example is provided, but in my case the solution was straightforward:

```
label="8.9 6 @~\141@~ = "$i;
```

Note that the first 2 numbers give the coordinates of the label, the `@~\141@~` gives the octal code for the character I want, the `@~` switches in and out of "Symbols" font/mode, and the other stuff is irrelevant.  As stated in the question, the full list of encodings in octal can be found [here](http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/classes/Intro_GMT/gmt_www/gmt/doc/html/GMT_Docs/node160.html).

Answer (score 1):

To activate the sign corresponding `\141` you have to activate it first using

```
gmt set PS_CHAR_ENCODING Standard+
```

or

```
gmt set PS_CHAR_ENCODING ISOLatin+
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know for future reference.